# How to get the user who created an Openshift project using OC cli?

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

When I login to openshift URL, under the URL/console/projects I can see all proejcts and who created them and when.
e.g.
:

```
actually
created by assafav 22 days ago
aggrdep
created by INNATR 22 days ago
```

:
how can i get this information using the oc cli?
I've tried "`oc status -v`" "`oc describe all`"
I'm using versions:

```
oc v3.10.14
kubernetes v1.10.0+b81c8f8
openshift v3.11.51
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0
```

Thanks

Comment: what you get with > `oc get projects`

Comment: Give this magic command a go: `oc get projects -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,OWNER:.metadata.annotations.openshift\\.io/requester,CREATED:.metadata.creationTimestamp`

Comment: Mr. @WillGordon - you the MAN!
This is what I was looking for.
Thanks

Comment: @WillGordon when you get time please move the comment to answer so its useful for people looking around .. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`oc get projects` works the same as any other `oc get` command. It's important to know the full flexibility of this command, specifically the `--output` flag:

```
$ oc get -h

...
  -o, --output='': Output format. One of:
json|yaml|wide|name|custom-columns=...|custom-columns-file=...|go-template=...|go-template-file=...|jsonpath=...|jsonpath-file=...
See custom columns [http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl-overview/#custom-columns], golang template
[http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#pkg-overview] and jsonpath template
[http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jsonpath].
...
```

In this case, `oc get projects -o custom-columns` will likely be the best approach, although others like `jsonpath` or `go-template` will provide even more flexibility in controlling the output in case you want to use another delimiter instead of tabs.

Selecting a *single* project and outputting it as yaml, `oc get project <project-name> -o yaml` will show you the full array of values that you are able to display.

To answer your specific question, on OpenShift the project creator is stored in a metadata annotation, `openshift.io/requester`, and the creation timestamp is also stored in the metadata. To display the project name, creator, and creation timestamp on the command line, you can do so with:

```
oc get projects -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,OWNER:.metadata.annotations.openshift\\.io/requester,CREATED:.metadata.creationTimestamp
```

(Note the `\\` is necessary to escape the `.` in `openshift.io`)

Answer (score -1):

`$ oc status` will give you status of current project you are in.

**To view list of projects current login has access to use**

```
$ oc get projects
```

> Note : you are restricted to listing only the projects with authorization.

To Change to project use

```
$ oc project <project_name>
```

Once switched with above command you can **get overview of the current project using**

```
$ oc status
```